# I need load load the array of items from an xml file but the top level does not read listed items

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

Using the System.Xml.Serialization I am trying to read an xml file in the structure below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootname xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AListItem>
    <someDataItem>1</someDataItem>
    <anotherItem>2</anotherItem>
  </AListItem>
  <AListItem>
    <someDataItem>3</someDataItem>
    <anotherItem>4</anotherItem>
  </AListItem>
  <Name>a string</Name>
</rootname>
```

My class structure:

```
public class rootname
{
    public rootname() { }

    [XmlElement("AListItem")]
    List<AListItem> DataList { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AListItem
{
    public AListItem() {}

    public string someDataItem { get; set; }
    public string anotherItem { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(openFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(rootname));
    rootname deserializedObject = xml.Deserialize(stream) as rootname;
}
```

The 'Name' property is loaded but the DataList is null.  How should the AListItem items be loaded?  is the XmlElement attribute correct?

Comment: where are you adding the AListItem objects to the list? maybe you should give us some more code, how do you read the xml file?

Comment: You need a collection node e.g. AListItems.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson changing the Xml file structure is not an option for me.  (The example given is just an example of the structure the actual file is more complex and is formed from a third party device.)

Comment: @Jane Doe code to read is: using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(openFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(rootname));
 rootname deserializedObject = xml.Deserialize(stream) as rootname;
} (added to question)

Comment: @james please edit your question with that code

Comment: @Jane Doe Yep, I did that after I found the code option was not available for comments.

Comment: @James. So you are saying you want to deserialise xml not produced by serialisation then? Have you got an xsd for it as well? If not I'd think about just loading it up direct with and XmlReader or some such, serialisation is very fragile, every time they sniff near the file you are going to be banging your head on your desk.

Comment: Ah just spotted you've adeded more to teh question, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tony I just realised the problem.  I forgot to make the list public!

```
public class rootname
{
    public rootname() { }

    [XmlElement("AListItem")]
    public List<AListItem> DataList { get; set; } // <<< public!

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Ohps.

Comment: I'd like to say nothing similar has ever happened to me, but I'd be telling a bit of a fib.